# Problem with query data range if a value is TRUE

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XFbSKOgwFlsRahaOOCq1-EZPR4JcmaT2ywUc2RQffnk/edit?usp=drivesdk

I use this sheet to list data of patients in my hospital. Also in the last tab (Possible_Discharge), I query all the patients that their value of column I is TRUE in the tab (All_Patients) using this query function:
`=query(All_Patients!B5:J,"select B,C,D,E,F,G,H where B is not null AND I =TRUE order by B",0)`

I also embedded code to clear contents of the sheet whenever I want to fill new data.

The problem I face is every time I fill new data after clearing the contents, The function of query (TRUE) results doesn't work. So, every time I change the TRUE to 'TRUE' or "TRUE" or just TRUE without quotation marks. I wonder what is wrong with this ?
Is there a way to rewrite the function?

NOTE:

- Data_Entry tab is where I fill the data of patients.
- All_Patients tab is generated by query function (view only) from Data_Entry tab.
- All_Patients tab Column I represents the column H in Data_Entry tab when the checkbox value is TRUE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `RangeList.clearContent()` method to remove data. This makes the value in the checkbox cells `null` instead of `false` or `true`.

The `query()` function only accepts one data type per column. The type of a column is determined by the majority of the values in the beginning of the column. When you clear the data, the data type of column `Data_Entry!H:H` is set to `null`, which means that the values that are `true` will not match the column type and will be considered `null` by `query()`.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Modify the `ClearContents()` function that clears the `Data_Entry` tab so that the checkboxes are set to `false` instead of setting them to `null`.
2. Replace your `query()` functions with `filter()`, like this:

`All_Patients!B5`:

```
=iferror( 
  sort( 
    filter( 
      { 
        Data_Entry!B5:B, Data_Entry!O5:O, Data_Entry!D5:E, Data_Entry!L5:L, Data_Entry!J5:K, Data_Entry!H5:H
      }, 
      Data_Entry!B5:B <> "Ward", 
      not(isblank(Data_Entry!F5:F)) + not(isblank(Data_Entry!G5:G)) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

`Possible_Discharge!D7`:

```
=iferror( 
  sort( 
    filter( 
      All_Patients!B5:H, 
      not(isblank(All_Patients!B5:B)), 
      All_Patients!I5:I = true 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Clearing contents will make values to false and won't delete checkboxes

Comment: Edited the answer to explain why `.clearContent()` makes the `query()` fail. Additional note: in `Trigger.gs`, the `onEdit(e)` function in broken and will generate an error every time any cell is edited. I think you can fix it by removing the `;
      ClearContents.sheet` bit.

Comment: That's great . Thank you alot